# Warning: mssql_execute(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-Statement resource

Tags: php

I try to run one of the stored proc with php. But somehow this is always display the following error message on the screen:

"Warning: mssql_execute(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-Statement resource..."

Please find below for my code for calling the stored proc in php:

```
$conn = mssql_connect("sql-02", "rsGreen", "abc123");
$db = mssql_select_db("Green");

$Query = "exec rpt_control @list = '".$_REQUEST['list']."',  
                  @suburb = '".$_REQUEST['suburb']."', 
                  @state = '".$_REQUEST['state']."', 
                  @on_off = ".$_REQUEST['switch'];

mssql_execute($Query );
```

Do anyone know how is going wrong with my code?

Note: When I'm manually run the stored proc, this is working fine and no error display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mssql_execute()` executes a prepared statement, not a string containing a SQL statement (which is the function of `mssql_query()`.  You will need to prepare a statement, bind parameters into it, and execute it:

```
// Prepare it with mssql_init()
$qry = mssql_init("rpt_control", $conn);
if ($qry) {

  // We assume these fields are all VARCHAR types...
  // If not, see the type constants listed on the mssql_bind() docs...
  mssql_bind($qry, '@list', $_REQUEST['list'], SQLVARCHAR);
  mssql_bind($qry, '@suburb', $_REQUEST['suburb'], SQLVARCHAR);
  mssql_bind($qry, '@state', $_REQUEST['state'], SQLVARCHAR);
  mssql_bind($qry, '@switch', $_REQUEST['switch'], SQLVARCHAR);

  // Then execute it
  mssql_execute($qry);

  // And free it
  mssql_free_statement($qry);
}
```

- [`mssql_execute()` docs](http://www.php.net/manual/function.mssql-execute.php)
- [`mssql_bind()` docs](http://www.php.net/manual/function.mssql-bind.php)

Although it would be possible to execute your stored procedure by building a SQL string and sending it to `mssql_query()`, doing so is not recommended when a prepared statement can be used.

Comment: I tried this.. but error message "Warning: mssql_execute() [function.mssql-execute]: message: Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection. This ensures consistent query semantics. Enable these options and then reissue your query" dispay

Comment: @JinYong So turn them on with `mssql_query("SET ANSI_NULLS ON; SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;");`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be using the `sqlsrv` functions instead of `mssql`, but you should refer to the [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-execute.php) before asking a question here as it can probably help you get to the root of your problem.  `mssql_execute()` requires a resource, not a string query.  You either need to create a stored procedure to call `mssql_init()` with, or in your case you can probably use `mssql_query()`.